# Django can't find the right queryset

Tags: python, django

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created = DateTimeField(_('created'), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified = DateTimeField(_('modified'), auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class TimeFramedModel(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(_('start'), null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(_('end'), null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class EntryQueryset(QuerySet):

    def published(self):
        return self.filter(self.status == 'published')


class EntryManger(models.Manager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        print 'using right custom manager'
        return EntryQueryset(self.model, using=self._db)

class Entry(TimeStampedModel, TimeFramedModel):

    status = models.CharField(
        _('status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=16,
        default='draft')
    objects = EntryManger()
```

When I do `Entry.objects.published()`, the error raises. It complains that 
'EntryManger' object has no attribute 'published',

The text of 'using right custom manager' wasn't printed.

What could cause this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Entry.objects` is a manager, not a queryset. You put `published` inside your custom queryset, so you need to do `Entry.objects.all().published()` or `Entry.objects.get_queryset().published()`

You also aren't implementing `published` correctly. It should be more like:

```
class EntryQueryset(QuerySet):

    def published(self):
        return self.filter(status='published')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `published()` should be on the EntryManager class, there is no need to create a new QuerySet class (generally that is only when you want to dig deeper into how data is fetched from the database).

The correct solution would be:

```
class EntryManger(models.Manager):
    def published(self):
        print 'using right custom manager'
        return self.filter(self.status == 'published')
```

You can delete the `EntryQuerySet` class entirely.